# How to update State without batching react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks, state

Assume i have the following state

```
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
```

here i have a function that does api call then some operation on the state i.e

```
    const getProducts=async()=>{
    // i use the page state in an api call
    ...
    //then afterward update the state
    setPage(page + 1);
    }
```

and I have a function Refresh that reset the State to initial value and calls the getProducts function

```
    const Refresh =()=>{
    setState(1)
    getProducts()
    }
```

the issue is when i call the refresh function the page state is not reset/updated and hence the api call is called with the page i don't want. What is the Error here and how do i go about it.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `getProducts` a parameter that would allow you to state the page (`currentPage`). If you pass `currentPage` it's used in the `setState`. If not, it sets `page + 1`:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

const getProducts = async(currentPage)=>{
  // i use the page state in an api call
  ...
  //then afterward update the state
  setPage(currentPage ?? page + 1);
}

const Refresh = () =>{
  getProducts(1)
}
```

React has a way to avoid batching states, but this effects the render of the JSX, and not the values inside the callback, for example:

```js
const { useState } = React
const { flushSync, createRoot } = ReactDOM

const Demo = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const [b, setB] = useState(0);

  const inc = () => {
    flushSync(() => {
      setA(a + 1)
    })
    
    setB(a)
    console.log(a)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={inc}>Increment</button>
      <div>a {a} - {b} b</div>
    </div>
  )
}

createRoot(root).render(<Demo />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: React has a way to avoid batch, but this won't effect the value inside the callback. See updated answer.